# How to save the state of a button after restarting the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

So I have a `button` which changes its image upon clicking. I would like to **save the state** of the `button` so that, when user reopens the app again, the `button` will display it's last state.

Below is my code:-

```
- (IBAction)xButtonOnPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.xButtonLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"x_did-not-take_marked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.xButtonLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"x_did-not-take.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.xButtonLabel.selected = !self.xButtonLabel.selected;

}
```

The problem with the code is that, it always goes back to `UIControlStateNormal` after restarting the app. How can I save the last button state ?

Comment: use NSUserDefault to save your button state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a button called button:

```
UIButton *button;

// get nsuserdefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// save selected state
[defaults setBool:button.selected forKey:@"myButtonState"];
```

Then later, after the app launches again...

```
// restore the selected state
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
button.selected = [defaults boolForKey:@"myButtonState"];
```

Comment: i want button unselected state also please help me.thanks

Answer (score 0):

use **NSUserDefaults** for this.

**Objective C:**

**To store:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"BUTTON_STATE_NORMAL"];
```

**To retrieve:**

```
Bool isNormalState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    boolForKey:@"BUTTON_STATE_NORMAL"];

if(isNormalState == true) {
  //Do your thing.
}
```

### **Additional:**

**swift 3:**

**To store:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("Your_button_state", forKey: "Key") //setObject
```

**To retrieve:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")
```

There are lots of data type in this.Choose how you want to save>:)